# SQL round function error for value 8.95

Tags: sql-server-2008, rounding

In SQL Server 2008:

```
declare @Value float
declare @result float 

set @Value=7.95
select @result=round(@Value,1)
print @result /*Prints 8*/

set @Value=8.95
select @result=round(@Value,1)
print @result /*Prints 8.9*/
```

The obtained result is 8.9 for 8.95, but if I put the value as 7.95 the result of the round function is 8.

Why do I get 8.9 instead of 9 for the value 8.95?

Comment: Get 9 on my machine (SQLServer 8 as well)

Comment: is it the floating point value, i get 9 on my machine if i declare it as decimal. For float, i got it as 8.9

Comment: Floating point (REAL and FLOAT) data is approximate. DECIMAL (NUMERIC) is exact: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way sql server is rounding your numbers:  When [the second parameter] is a positive number, numeric_expression is rounded to the number of decimal positions specified by length.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

Comment: then why its getting 8 for 7.975?

Comment: Please post the exact code you are running which demonstrates this issue and test on your machine that it reproduces the behaviour first. The code in your question is not runnable so this is clearly not the exact code. `@result=round(@Value,1)` is not valid without a `set` or `select`

Comment: @AnoopMohan - The code you have posted still isn't runnable so you clearly haven't bothered checking that the sample you posted demonstrates the issue even on your own machine.

Comment: @MartinSmith- Ok then can help me to round(8.95) and get me the result as 9 for a float value...and one more thing. the above code is working fine on my machine. i don know why u r getting errors

Comment: @AnoopMohan - because you left out the `select` in `select @result=round(@value,1)`... as Martin already told you.

Comment: ok @Lieven i changed that one...

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith for Correcting me...but why it is getting 8.9 instead of 9

Comment: @AnoopMohan - I get the same results as you. Floating point is imprecise as @Ivan said. Try adding `SELECT CAST(@Value AS DECIMAL(38,37))` after you set the value. For me `SELECT CAST(CAST(8.95 AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(38,37))` gives `8.9499999999999993000000000000000000000`. This is less than `8.95` hence rounding down. And `SELECT CAST(CAST(7.95 AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(38,37))` gives `7.9500000000000001000000000000000000000` which is greater than `7.95` so rounds up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point (REAL and FLOAT) data is approximate. DECIMAL (NUMERIC) is exact: [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
That might be the reason for this seemingly inconsistent behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

For 8.975,it gives 9 only. You should have used this instead,
`@result=round(@value,1,1)`